# Rails 6, how can I create custom primary key with migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to create custom primary key in rails 6, but didn't created primary key,
it's created normal id.

migration i have given

```
def change
create_table(:m_user_status, :id => false) do |t|
  t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
  t.string :status_name, limit: 20
  t.integer :status_check
  t.timestamps
end
```

from above just created id with int4 type, but i want create id with type int4 and primary key without auto-increment.
how i give id without auto-incremented and type int4(integer normal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine the `:id` and `:primary_key` options according to the docs here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table

For example:

```
class CreatedummyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :dummy_table, id: :int4, primary_key: :foo do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Creates this schema in postgres:

```
create_table "dummy_table", primary_key: "foo", id: :integer,  default: nil, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Comment: sir, i didn't want to change with schema file, that's why i have tried with another solution, it's work